# "Failed to load resource" error when loading photos on github pages with reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, routes, github-pages

I recently deployed a react website on github pages but my photos keep failing to load. I'm not sure what the problem is

github pages website: https://connoryoung2.github.io/photo-gallery/
github repo: https://github.com/connoryoung2/photo-gallery

I have tried changing the directory of the photos (ie. ./photos/photo.png to ../photos/photo.png) and making sure that each link to each photo is capatilized correctly. Maybe I'm doing this wrong though.

Answer (score 1):

write like this

`<img src="/photo-gallery/photos/stel_curt.jpg" alt="Gallery Image" class="home-img img-fade active">`

(it works only with bundlers) you can also import photo in component and insert in img src and then your paths will be alright

```
import photo from './photos/lmK8L8nRkqk.jpg';

export default function App() {
  return <img src={photo} alt="" />;
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).